# How to map a LoadBalancer ListenerRule on a specific port using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I am using CloudFormation to create a stack for my application.

The stack consists of an existing LoadBalancer in which I want to add a new Port Mapping rule for which forwards requests to my application.

```
LoadBalancerRule:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
      - TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup'
        Type: 'forward'
     Conditions:
      - Field: path-pattern
        Values: [!Ref 'PortMapping']
     ListenerArn:
       Fn::ImportValue:
       !Join [':', [!Ref 'StackName']]
         Priority: !Ref 'Priority'
```

I'm trying to figure out what the correct conditions would be to create a  LoadBalancer Listener with PortMapping 8080 to my existing LoadBalancer, to create the following:

[image]

So far, I have not been able to create a mapping via a Port number, only by a path pattern on the default port 80.

I've looked at the questions on Stackoverflow, and the ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule resource page, but I haven't found a working solution yet. 
 Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-listenerrule.html

Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for listeners for 8080 and 443:

```
"ELB": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
  "Properties": {
    "Subnets": { "Ref": "Subnet" },
    "HealthCheck": {
      "HealthyThreshold": "2",
      "Interval": "10",
      "Target": "HTTP:80/health",
      "Timeout": "8",
      "UnhealthyThreshold": "6"
    },
    "Listeners": [
      {
        "InstancePort": "80",
        "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP",
        "LoadBalancerPort": "8080",
        "Protocol": "HTTP"
      },
      {
        "InstancePort": "80",
        "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP",
        "LoadBalancerPort": "443",
        "Protocol": "HTTPS",
        "SSLCertificateId": {"Ref": "SSLArn"}
      }
    ],
    "SecurityGroups": [
      { "Ref": "ELBSG" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And for yaml:

`ELB:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
  Properties:
    Subnets:
      Ref: Subnet
    HealthCheck:
      HealthyThreshold: '2'
      Interval: '10'
      Target: HTTP:80/health
      Timeout: '8'
      UnhealthyThreshold: '6'
    Listeners:
    - InstancePort: '80'
      InstanceProtocol: HTTP
      LoadBalancerPort: '8080'
      Protocol: HTTP
    - InstancePort: '80'
      InstanceProtocol: HTTP
      LoadBalancerPort: '443'
      Protocol: HTTPS
      SSLCertificateId:
        Ref: SSLArn
    SecurityGroups:
    - Ref: ELBSG`

And the following is about updating the listener rule:

`Listener:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    DefaultActions:
    - Type: forward
      TargetGroupArn:
        Ref: myTargetGroup
    LoadBalancerArn:
      Ref: myLoadBalancer
    Port: '8080'
    Protocol: HTTP`

I hope that this is what you were looking for. Please update if more help is needed.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I was wondering if there was a way to update my existing yml based rule in the above format?  However, I am currently trying to convert the above into yml.

Comment: will make your life easier - i converted and updated the answer above :)

Comment: Thank you :) That's awesome!

Comment: No problem. Please let me know if that helped. If so, please don't forget to mark it as answered :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks, although this solution creates a new Load Balancer, rather than updating an existing one.  I believe that the solution will use the `Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule`

Comment: So maybe you just missing the port property in your example?
I updated the answer with an example.